# 22.04; Open file dialogue opens in the wrong monitor 50% of the time, in fact it alternates, correct monitor, wrong monitor, rinse and repeat

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, dialog, amazon

Essentially I've only observed this when writing a product review on Amazon. I click to add a photo and a file dialogue opens, if it opens on the primary monitor, the next time I click to add a file the dialogue will pop up on the second monitor.
Then next time the primary, and... around we go again.

Oddly I have not observed this when I had Zorin installed for a short time.

I've searched this, but I can't find anyone else reporting this behaviour, but I have seen it on three machines, three different installs of 22.04.

Edit. I have found this consistently happens in all the browsers I have installed, so Firefox, Chrome, Brave and Opera, again across different installs/architecture.

Comment: I suppose this is happening for you in the browser? Firefox? Better add this info to your question to be more specific

Comment: I will edit, it actually happens in every browser I have installed, Firefox, Chrome, Brave and Opera.

Comment: Also in Chrome which is installed as a .deb? I suspect this issue is related to containerized applications (snap, but eventually also flatpak and appimage)

Comment: Yes it happens in chrome which I installed as a .deb via the software centre.

Interestingly when I chose the option in the Extension "Dash to Panel" to have the task bar on the primary monitor only - the problem reappeared.
But with the task bar on the bottom (as Zorin hence why I tried this) on both screens the dialogue opens in the same screen as the browser.

I should note the reason why this bugged me was I have a media PC - so the second monitor is a big TV with the primary as standard monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Well randomly (at least from my limited user-knowledge perspective) installing the Gnome Extension "Dash to Panel" fixed this behaviour.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/

Edit. But only if the task bar is displayed on both monitors.

And the dialogue window "grows" eventually crossing into the other screen, however the window can be resized by dragging when open in the primary window to constrain this.